# PolarStereographic cannot set latitudeOfOrigin (standardParallel) in Geotools

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

We have [geotiff](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/32815/20170921T235500Z.geotif) file with metadata as below, and we are not able to create the proper `PolarStereographic` coordinate system.

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",60],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",10],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

During transformation units from PolarStereographic projection to EPSG3857_WEBMERCATOR projection, standardParallel variable from PolarStereographic class is used. And despite fact, that `latitude_of_origin` is equal 60 
(see configuration above), standardParallel is set automatically to 90 degrees. That's why projection after transforming is moved to the top.
We are using version 17.2

Is there a way to set `latitude_of_origin` of PolarStereographic projection, other than Java Reflection API?

Answer (score 3):

Because you have told GeoTools that you want a **Polar**_Sterographic projection it [assumes that you want to use one of the poles](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/referencing/src/main/java/org/geotools/referencing/operation/projection/PolarStereographic.java#L155) as the origin. If you ask for an Oblique_Stereographic instead it will work fine.

```
String wkt = "PROJCS[\"unnamed\",\n" + 
    "    GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",\n" + 
    "        DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",\n" + 
    "            SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n" + 
    "                AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],\n" + 
    "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],\n" + 
    "        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],\n" + 
    "        UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n" + 
    "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],\n" + 
    "    PROJECTION[\"Oblique_Stereographic\"],\n" + 
    "    PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",60],\n" + 
    "    PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",10],\n" + 
    "    PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",1],\n" + 
    "    PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],\n" + 
    "    PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],\n" + 
    "    UNIT[\"metre\",1,\n" + 
    "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]]]";
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.parseWKT(wkt );
```

Comment: Thank you @iant! I've just tried your solution but it didn't work out for me. Image ends up way too south. It shows up over North Africa but expected to be over Germany.